# php calling soap function using client certificate

Tags: php, soap, ssh, certificate, handshake

I am facing an issue with calling soap function. I am getting error "Could not connect to host". I am using "wamp server", "php version 5.3.13" and "apache version 2.2.22".

I have client certificate in .p12 format, wsdl file available at local system and i have tested soap call using soapUI-m-snapshot. It works fine! But when i am trying same with php "SoapClient" getting "Could not connect to host".
I am using following soap options

```
$soapclient_options = array();
$soapclient_options['cache_wsdl'] = 'WSDL_CACHE_NONE';
$soapclient_options['local_cert'] = $certificatePath;
$soapclient_options['passphrase'] = $api_certificate_passphrase;
$soapclient_options['trace'] = true;
$soapclient_options['connection_timeout'] = 15;
$soapclient_options['ssl_method'] = 'SOAP_SSL_METHOD_SSLv3';
$soapclient_options['location'] = 'api location';

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl_path, $soapclient_options);
$client->__setLocation($soapclient_options['location']);
```

Am i doing something in wrong way?
Someone please suggest me and many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP Soap client accepts only pem certificates. You can covert your certificate  using:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in in.p12 -out out.pem -nodes -clcerts
```

Comment: Thanks Greg, I found same somewhere and worked for me.

Comment: Can you mark my answer as correct for future reference. Thank you.

Comment: Ohh! i forgot, i am new here.

Answer (score -1):

Additional code needed to make it work with PHP 5.6 version.

```
$soapclient_options['stream_context'] = stream_context_create(
            array(
                'ssl' => array(
                    'verify_peer' => false,
                    'verify_peer_name' => false,
                )
            )
    );
```

Comment: Please don't do that! It will make your connection less secure and vulnerable to man in the middle attacks! It makes your client accept ANY certificate and not only yours!

Comment: This is because your certificate is probably selfsigned and not verified by some global authority (Certificate Authority) Proper solution is to have server certificate and to trust only that one certificate. More here (example is for curl BUT it also works fine for all streams - file_get_contents, soap etc.): http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

Comment: Thanks @Greg i am not using this solution. I already have moved to different authentication system.